# Reload location after sending a form with JSON

Tags: jquery, json, reload

I have a contact form. What I want to do, is when the user filled in the form and it passed all the checks (see if the field not empty, if the email is in fact an email etc...), it should display a confirmation message with animation and after the animation is done - reload the page.

So I tried it like that:

```
$.getJSON("inc/API.php", {
    command: "send_contact_form",
    ...rest of the keys and values...
}, function () {
    clear_form();
    $("#form_confirmation").animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 1000, function () {
        setTimeout($("#form_confirmation").animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 3000), 6000, function () {
            location.reload()
        });
    });
});
```

Everything works, except for the reload. I tried it in different locations, but I still don't see a reload of the page. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried putting a console.log() in there to see if it ever reaches the reload statement?

Comment: You're passing your `location.reload()` function as a third argument to setTimeout, which will be ignored.  You need to pass it to `animate` instead.

Comment: What is the logic behind using the **setTimeout()** inside animate callback?

Comment: @PalashMondal - It's probably to give users a chance to see the confirmation message before reloading the page.

Comment: @Joe Yes, that's was the logic. Though the execution was incorrect on my part.

Comment: @RichieHindle Yes, that was my problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#form_confirmation").animate({opacity:0}, 3000, function(){
        location.reload();
    });
},6000);
```

You currently have the `location.reload()` function as a third `setTimeout()` argument which isn't correct. The code above will reload the page once the confirmation message has been faded out.